# cant retrieve bulk images from media library

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

i am trying to retrieve images from media library it works fine when images are few like 20 25 but as there are more i think 34 exactly i get this exception 
System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled

am using this code

```
    foreach (Picture p in cameraRoll.Pictures)
           {
               BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage();
               b.SetSource(p.GetImage());
               flib.Add(new fromlibrary() { bmp = b, name = p.Name });
               b = null;
           }
```

where cameraRoll is PictureAlbum and flib is a list<>
also as images increase load time is increasing what can i do about it???
all the loading is done inside BackgroundWorker Dowork....

Answer (score 1):

i figured out i just hav to use p.GetThumbnail()
showed a whooping difference in peak memory consumption......
GetThumbnail()--28.01Mb
GetImage()--128Mb